# Block property binding when value changed in one way

Tags: qt, qml

I don't know if exist different solution for my problem but this is what I would like to obtain.

```
MyItem.qml

Item {
    id: myItem
    property double myValue: 0.0

    TextField {
        text: Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1)
        onTextChanged: myItem.myValue= Number.parseFloat(text)
    }
}
```

Using this control in a separate qml file work but generate a loop warning caused by the change of myValue property. However the myValue property need to be changed dynamically by the separate qml file code so how to fix the problem? I need that the myValue property to be always updated to the current text value converted and the same if the myValue is assigned externally need to be showed immediately in the text control.

Best way could be to stop the property binding when assigned by the onTextChanged event but is possible? Any other suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A simple patch is you can property-bind to *either* `myValue` or `undefined` based on whether the `TextField` has activeFocus:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        MyItem { id: myItem }
        Button { text: "PI"; onClicked: myItem.myValue = Math.PI }
    }
}

// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Frame {
    id: myItem
    property double myValue: 0.0
    padding: 0
    TextField {
        id: textField
        text: !activeFocus ? Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1) : undefined
        onTextChanged: myItem.myValue = Number.parseFloat(text)
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAB9nicdVBNa8MwDL3nV2g9JRe3u2aMwQKBwjpSGLu7sZaa2VbmyKOh5L8vadJ0LZtu78l+H9K2Js+w5W3Q5Wekr6DIyLEn09zyL7KlwE1UyArhGEE/GZlg3biYqGE27ZrRwhG0SsGOoJu3z4GZXL9lPHAKi2K9eABymelNcP4gbPsuTUB4hI3kvSjWk0QXdVG0XE4m4suam6D/9sm9tOfkl2QnWHuq0XMLisLOIEzmKazEanwgldKu6okTfOuj5xqN+tV6kOQzP7NjyTtZsv7GnMrQwBO8BrtDH183TQRTrg+o4vsEUghO4Yd2eJEiN9hme+mqP+80qopa+gZzQ5LjwTw5X+0HXSGfcA==)

Alternatively, you may like to consider using the `Binding` component and make use of the `when` property:

```
// MyItem.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Frame {
    id: myItem
    property double myValue: 0.0
    padding: 0
    TextField {
        id: textField
        onTextChanged: myItem.myValue = Number.parseFloat(text)
    }
    Binding {
        textField.text: Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1)
        when: !activeFocus
    }
}
```

However, in my tests, I have found the latter implementation to be quite quirking with the values jumping to historical values when you click on/off the TextField.

N.B. I've replaced `Item` with `Frame` to get around the `Item` sizing problem. If you do not do this, `Item` defaults to 0 width and 0 height. You can see the TextField when used with Item because no clipping is enforced.

Comment: Hi, at first thank you for the time you found in reply me. Regarding Binding restoring the original value you need to use the Binding.RestoreNone flag if you don't want such behavior. However your solution doesn't work for be because I need to myValue property to be always updated with the current value on the text field and not when the control lost focus. In add of this this control is part of closable popup and I don't know if the popup is closed the lost focus event is generated...

Comment: But the first answer does exactly that?

Comment: These 2 solutions produce binding loop warnings. They fail to stop the `onTextChanged` signal handler to be executed.
For the first one, you can't assign an undefined to the text property, it also produces a warning message. It could work if the property had a RESET function but it would be equivalent to setting an empty text. Not what the OP want.
For the Binding one, it's missing the restore mode as mentioned by Suppaman. It also uses a non-documented syntax and implicit context access.

Comment: The Frame is not really relevant here, and could simply be removed to have the TextField as the root item. In other case (not the first time Frame is recommended) with no QQC2, a Control with a contentItem set is enough if you want to support padding.

Answer (score 0):

Qt Quick Controls 2 provide a signal mechanism specially for this use. They have an "interaction" signal in parallel of the usual `<property>Modified` signal. This signal will only emit when user interaction causes the value to change.

In the case of `TextField` it's the `textEdited` signal.
The following code should do the trick:

```
TextField {
    text: Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1)
    onTextEdited: myItem.myValue = Number.parseFloat(text)
}
```

Examples of other such signals:
`CheckBox` `toggled`, `ComboBox` `activated`, `Slider` `moved`, `SpinBox` `valueModified`, …

EDIT:
Since the text is formatted with toFixed, it can be unintuitive when trying to type a value with 2 decimals since it would be immediately changed to only 1 (and rounded).
To fix that you could use the `editingFinished` (emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the text input loses focus) signal instead of `textEdited` or use a conditional Binding to not update while editing:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
    Binding on text {
        when: !textField.activeFocus
        value: Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1)
        restoreMode: Binding.RestoreNone
    }
    onTextEdited: myItem.myValue = Number.parseFloat(text)
    onAccepted: focus = false
}
```

Alternatively, and to support reverting to the backend value with escape you can do a mix of both like so:

```
TextField {
    id: textField
    Binding on text {
        when: !textField.activeFocus
        value: Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1)
        restoreMode: Binding.RestoreNone
    }
    onEditingFinished: {
        myItem.myValue = Number.parseFloat(text);
        focus = false;
    }
    Keys.onEscapePressed:  {
        text = Number(myItem.myValue).toFixed(1);
        focus = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, as other user I want to first thank you for the time you found in reply me. However I don't understand the difference in your solution to use onTextEdited. When the text is changed the new value is reported in the myValue property that, in a loop mode for the binding, return to the text property...,

Comment: There shouldn't be any loop. `textEdited` is only fired when the user types stuff in.
For example, the user types in a new value, the `onTextEdited` signal handler is called, assigning a new value to `myItem.myValue`. That causes the notify signal to be emitted, the `text` binding then get reevaluated. The `textChanged` signal is emitted but there is no signal handler for it , the `textEdited` signal is not emitted since the change is not due to user intereaction --> no loop.

Comment: I'll do some tests, thank you